# How can I let typescript know the return type of a function that is dependent on the passed in argument

Tags: typescript

I am trying to do something like this with typescript

```
class Test {
  someMethod(){}
}

const foo = {
  'someStringThatMeansTest': new Test,
}

function createClass(classReferenceName) {
  return foo[classReferenceName];
}

const test = createClass('someStringThatMeansTest');
```

and I'm wondering if it's possible to have typescript figure out the return type of createClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can restrict the type of argument to `foo`'s keys, then typescript will be able to infer the return type properly:

```
function createClass<T extends keyof typeof foo>(classReferenceName: T) {
  return foo[classReferenceName];
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Test%20%7B%0A%20%20someMethod()%20%7B%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Test2%20%7B%0A%20%20someMethod()%20%7B%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20foo%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20'someStringThatMeansTest'%3A%20new%20Test%2C%0A%20%20'someStringThatMeansTest2'%3A%20new%20Test2%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20createClass%3CT%20extends%20keyof%20typeof%20foo%3E(classReferenceName%3A%20T)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20foo%5BclassReferenceName%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20test%20%3D%20createClass('someStringThatMeansTest')%3B%0Aconst%20test2%20%3D%20createClass('someStringThatMeansTest2')%3B)